# Java (or Groovy) equivalent of Scala's apply

Tags: java, groovy

In Scala if there is an object `Foo` that has `apply(x: Int)` I can call it with `Foo(42)` (as shorthand for `Foo.apply(42)`).

Is it possible to replicate this in either Java or Groovy? I had thought maybe Groovy's `call` would function similar but neither `def call(int x)` or `static def call(int x)` resulted in calling `call`

**EDIT**: adding example DSL as requested

Typical/existing DSL: `alter 't' add 'a' storing BAR` (where `BAR` is an enum).
Attempting to add something that will take the place of `BAR` in the above but will accept an argument, but without differing the syntax *too* much, ideally: `alter 't' add 'a' storing FOO(42)`

I've created FOO as a class with a constructor that accepts an int - what I'm looking for now is a way to call that constructor by `FOO(42)` instead of `new FOO(42)` or `FOO.call(42)`

Comment: cool question can you provide more info

Comment: @KickButtowski it's for a DSL where normally enums are called but need to add something that takes an argument - so it's implemented as a class instead of an enum. But ideally I'd like to keep the DSL syntax for this special case as close as possible to the other cases. `FOO(42)` is closer to `FOO` than `new FOO(42)` or `FOO.call(42)`

Comment: @Exupery can you post some examples of your DSL? There might be some workaround on this

Comment: A DSL in general is a pretty good idea but after messing with a few I absolutely hate the idea of bastardizing some language to make a hybred that is not recognizable as either the original language or a "Natural language".  If you are going to write a DSL, why not just go ahead and parse it yourself?  That way you get the exact language you are looking for and.not_some random english_like.text.with bizarre_syntax_requireme.nts??

Comment: @WillP added example DSL

Comment: @BillK the DSL allows developers to write database agnostic SQL that will then get mapped to database-specific SQL for multiple databsaes - seems like a good use of DSL to me. Besides, *not* writing/using a DSL isn't an option anyway, I'm a very junior engineer at a very large enterprise :-)

Comment: If you already know you can do it in Scala why not just do it in Scala? I'm not a fan of overly-complex internal DSLs for precisely this reason-it's often more work, only to create something that doesn't quite feel right, and could be handled more generally by using a simple till like ANTLR or a PEG library. YMMV.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm a **huge** fan of Scala, but it obviously isn't sensible to rewrite an entire project just to make use of a language's feature for one line of code. Plus, as I mentioned in a previous comment "I'm a very junior engineer at a very large enterprise" - which language(s) we use for a project isn't exactly up to me.

Comment: Sorry--to some degree these comments are general, a lot of people might read this question so it is reasonable to mention the problems bending some existing language into a DSL, my advise may not fit your situation--plus that sounds like a GREAT use for a DSL (I really like them).  My only issue is that trying to make a DSL that can be interpreted by a compiler/interpreter, but even then it's sometimes kind of appropriate and maybe it totally works in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward way in Groovy would be to write a `static call()` method on the class, but it doesn't make `Clazz()` work. It might be a bug, but i couldn't find a JIRA about it.

I'd like to suggest using closures:

```
import groovy.transform.Canonical as C

@C class Bar { def bar }

@C class Baz { def baz }

A = { new Bar(bar: it) }

B = { new Baz(baz: it) }


assert A("wot") == new Bar(bar: "wot")
assert B("fuzz") == new Baz(baz: "fuzz")
```

---

**Update**: seems like the class name is resolved as an static method call in the callee context, this works (but it's not usable in a DSL):

```
class A { 
    static call(str) { str.toUpperCase() } 
}
assert ((Class)A)("qwop") == "QWOP"
```

---

**Update 2:** As per your DSL example, would removing the parens be feasible?

```
class FOO {}


def params = [:]

alter = { 
  params.alter = it
  [add : { 
      params.add = it
      [storing: { 
          params.clazz = it
          [:].withDefault { params.param = it }
      }]
  }]
}


alter 't' add 'a' storing FOO 42


assert params == [
  alter : 't',
  add   : 'a',
  clazz : FOO,
  param : '42'
]
```

Comment: Using `@Canonical` was impeccable. :)

Comment: Removing the parens would absolutely be okay - but your example rewrites all the DSL, which is definitely not. I would need a solution that handles the `FOO 42` portion completely independent of anything else.

Comment: @Exupery is the first example, using closures, suitable?

Comment: Yes the one with closures is suitable! Sorry for not noticing that yesterday - I didn't feel I had a good place to stick the equivalent of `A = { new Bar(bar: it) }` but looking at it again I realized I can throw that in a static method on the enum (holding all the other/normal "FOOs") and name the method `FOO`. I then of course realized I can just stick `return new FOO(x)` in that method, ha. Thanks for getting me down the right path! [And your answer definitely addresses the generic/original form of my question]

Comment: `call()` also works on enums, if that helps in any way: `enum P { E; def call() { "wot" } }; assert P.E() == "wot"`

Answer (score 0):

`Closure` in Groovy has method `call()` that can be ommitted:

```
def action = { a, b = 1 -> println "$a and $b" }
action.call 1 // prints "1 and 1"
action( 1, 3 ) // prints "1 and 3"
```

In Java the closest alternative is the `Runnable`: it provides no-arg `run()` but cannot be short-handed

Comment: also works on classes `class Foo { def call(x) { println x } }; foo = new Foo(); foo(42)`

Comment: @cfrick comment should be an answer.

Comment: @cfrick will it work with static `call`? Just wondering if exactly the same scala syntax is possible here.

Comment: @cfrick that's closer to what I'm looking for, but would need it without instantiating Foo

Comment: @Opal seems not to work by simply adding `static`.  Also `call.metaClass.Foo` does not work at first glance.

Comment: @cfrick, indeed, i tried with `method.invokeStaticMethod`, `class A { static call(){} }`, and also `doCall`, and no cigar